# Graph Sketching and Transformations

Tags: graphing-functions

Sketch the following

$$y = f(x)$$
$$y^2 = f(x)$$
$$y = f(x^2)$$
$$y^2 = f(x^2)$$

Obviously you can't sketch these, but how does each graph differ from the first one, i.e. how are they transformed and is there a general idea behind all of these?

Comment: why don't you do $f(x) = x^3?$ Illustrates some of the issues well.

Comment: To understand this you should try using the graph of $y=\sqrt {x}$ as an example.